# How to use cookies from a component?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

How can I use cookies in a Joomla component?

```
setcookie( JUtility::getHash('JLOGIN_REMEMBER'), false, time() - 86400, '/' );
```

Can anybody describe how this works?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
// Get input cookie object
$inputCookie  = JFactory::getApplication()->input->cookie;

// Get cookie data
$value        = $inputCookie->get($name = 'myCookie', $defaultValue = null);

// Check that cookie exists
$cookieExists = ($value !== null);

// Set cookie data
$inputCookie->set($name = 'myCookie', $value = '123', $expire = 0);

// Remove cookie
$inputCookie->set('myCookie', null, time() - 1);
```

### Some rules about `$expire` value

- its a [Unix tinestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp) in seconds, like return value of `time()`.
- `$expire == 0`: cookie lifetime is of browser session.
- `$expire < time()`: cookie is being deleted (expire set to past).
   You could remove cookie by setting it's value to null, but apparently IE fails to do so.

### Notes

*Keep in mind that cookies should be set before headers are sent (usually before output is echoed).*

*Cookie key and value should be properly escaped*

### Non-string values

When serializing the value on set (like `json_encode($dataNode)`), remember to use proper filter to retrieve it later on. Default is `cmd`, which filters out pretty much anything but a-Z, 0-9 and cracks JSON structure.

```
// Get cookie data
$encodedString = $inputCookie->get('myCookie', null, $filter = 'string');

// Decode
$values = json_decode($encodedString);

// Encode and Set
$inputCookie->set('myCookie', json_encode($values));
```

### Rererences

- Joomla CMS github repository: [JInputCookie::set](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/input/cookie.php#L47) (very well documented)
- php docs: [php.net/setcookie](http://www.php.net/setcookie) (developer experiences)
- Wikipedia: [HTTP Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) (theory)

Comment: The value MUST NOT be an array, joomla does not support subcookies as of now

Comment: @piotr_cz On the third line for the check if cookie exists, shouldn't the comparison operator be `!==` ?