# When refresh the page Cookies are deleting in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, cookies, joomla2.5

I am using below code to set cookie in joomla 2.5 version.

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->("ndt_engine_size", $_POST['engine_size'], time() + (86400 * 365));
```

But when we refresh the page cookie is deleting. Any one know what can be the reason.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tried to use this:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->cookie;
```

I leave a comment if you can use them.

This answer is of @piotr_cz: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16230742/4159485

Hope that helps.